# How to make DNN textfield readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

How do you make a textfield readonly in DotNetNuke?

I have this code but its not working:

```
DnnFormTextBoxItem.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`?

Comment: Is this in a custom module, on an existing module, or somewhere else?

Comment: It's an existing control but it is still editable after setting the enabled property to false.

Comment: @Owen....have you tried the ReadOnly property?

Comment: I tried readonly but it didn't work, I resolved the issue though with the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DotnetNuke, I only use dnn tag for text editor, with text field I use asp:TextBox tag and it can be disable or set readonly. But if you use dnn:Texteditor then there is no way to disable or set it to readonly. It only can be setted to visible or invisible.

Another solution for disable a texteditor in DotnetNuke is to retrive value from texteditor and paste it to a label then hide the text editor.

I have a short code here in C#. Imagine that you have a TextEditor1 and Label1 controls in your page and they are stay side-to-side to other but Label1 have an empty value. There is the code behind to setting an attribute for DNN TextEditor:

```
string teValue = TextEditor1.Value;
Label1.Text = teValue;
TextEditor1.Visible = false;
```

In the code above, you will show value of TextEditor1 in a Label (Label1) and then hide the TextEditor1 control, so that user only see the content of DNN TextEditor but nolonger be able to edit it after doing some post-back.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people use

```
<dnn:DnnFormLiteralItem>
```

In my modules, I use the standard

```
<asp:TextBox>
```